# Calculating a Matching in a Bipartite Graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Coming from **Hall's Theorem** that for there to be a matching, $|N(S)| \ge |S|$, it seems very difficult to check if there is a matching in a bipartite graph if the set grows quite large.

Rather than checking by hand to see if each subset of the set has a matching, is there an easier way to compute this?

Thanks!

Comment: If I recall correctly, the usual way of going about this is using an algorithm for computing a maximum cardinality match in a bipartite graph. You can find some such methods in Wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_cardinality_matching

Comment: There are indeed algorithms that find a maximum matching in a graph--it doesn't even have to be bipartite, and that do so efficiently.

Comment: @Mike I'm not asking about a maximum matching, I'm asking about the overall matching. I only care about whether all the subsets of the above set in the claim have a matching. I've researched some solutions regarding the degree of one side of a bipartite graph related to the other, but it is a bit confusing.

Comment: All the subsets $S$ in the above claim have a matching that covers every vertex in $S$ if the maximum matching is a perfect matching i.e. covers every vertex in the side of the bipartite graph you are intetested in. At least this is what I think you are asking.

Comment: @Mike Yes, that is exactly what I am asking.